# Pass selected language from uib-dropdown language selector to $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

I have next html template where user could select language:

```
 <div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" uib-dropdown-toggle>
                        <span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" lang="en"></span><span class="caret logincaret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" uib-dropdown-menu >
                        <li><span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" lang="hu"></span></li>
                        <li><span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" lang="ru"></span></li>                        
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

How to bind selected option lang attribute to controllers $scope?

**UPDATE:**

The desirable result is [here](http://usrz.github.io/bootstrap-languages/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd want to use a simple select for this:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selected" ng-options="o as o for o in ['hu', 'ru']"></select>
```

Then you'd have it much simpler and the model is bound correctly (in `$scope.selected`)

As far as I know, the dropdown is useful for actions as a menu, not for binding a selected value.

Alternatively, to continue using the dropdown, you'll need to manage the value updates yourself (e.g. using ng-click on the drop-down actions)

Something like this:

```
<div class="btn-group uib-dropdown">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" uib-dropdown-toggle>
    <span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" lang="{{selected}}"></span> <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" uib-dropdown-menu >
    <li ng-repeat="lang in ['hu','ru']" ng-click="selected = lang"><span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" lang="{{lang}}"></span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: See my update. I`m trying to create language selection box.

Comment: Ok, then you'd need to maintain the model yourself, because there is no ng-model on dropdowns - see edit